# How to remove the error related to modulus in the challenge 'Sam and sub-strings'?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, modulus

I was doing a problem named [Sam and sub-strings](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sam-and-substrings) on hackerrank which you can look by clicking on the corresponding link.

Here is my code. I am sure that the logic of my program is correct as it works for smaller values (and also the sample test cases). The problem is with modulus and I am not able to get how to use modulus in this program correctly. Can anyone please help me (if possible, please tell when/where to use modulus in the program without editing the rest of my program)?
My submission gives correct results for testcases 0,1,2,3,12 and incorrect results for the rest.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {  
    long long int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<long long int> v1;
    while (n!=0){
        v1.push_back(n%10);
        n=n/10;
    }

    long long int x=1,s1=0,sum=0;
    for (long long int i=v1.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
        s1+=x*v1[i];
        x++;
        sum=(sum+(s1*(long long int)pow(10,i))%1000000007)%1000000007;
    }

    cout << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered keeping the number as a text string?  You can fetch the digits using array notation.  You can convert the digit to a number by subtracting `'0'`.

Comment: You can eliminate the calls to `pow` by maintaining a variable that is multiplied by 10 in each loop.  This will improve the performance of your code and with online judges, time is a factor.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, if there's modular arithmetic, there cannot also be a floating point `pow`.

Comment: @harold I am converting floating point pow to long long int by type casting. So that is not the issue.

Comment: @user3774008 sure it's not an issue this time, but only because the exponent is tiny. There's no reason to use it here though, and in general it's dangerous to even try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you treat the number as text when playing with digits.

```
int main()
{
  std::string number_as_text; 
  std::cin >> number_as_text;

  long long sum = 0;
  const std::string::size_type length = number_as_text.length();
  for (unsigned int index = 0; index < length; ++index)
  {
      long long s1 = (number_as_text[index] - '0') * (index + 1);
      sum = sum * 10 + s1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You'll have to figure out where to put the *mod 1000000007* in your program, if you need to.

Also, I recommend placing error handling in the code, especially when reading in the number.  The function `std::isdigit` looks helpful.